# Unable to make API calls using access_token for private Stack Overflow Teams site

Tags: support, api-v2.2, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am attempting to create an application utilizing the API to query data from our private Stack Overflow Teams site.

I've read through the documentation at https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams and https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication, but to no avail.

My problem is simply that my requests to the API are denied with the following error:

`` {"error_id":403,"error_message":"`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.","error_name":"access_denied"} ``

In order to keep our site anonymous, I will simply refer to it as "foosite" in the following text.

What I have done, in order:

- Used the explicit OAuth API, server side, to generate an access_token using 
  `scope=access_team%7cstackoverflow.com%f2c%f2foosite,no_expiry`.
- Passed this access_token using the `X-API-Access-Token` header for my GET request to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered/?team_url=stackoverflow.com%2fc%2ffoosite&site=stackoverflow&key=u9eRD30bklGv9t9gzDRSAQ((`

What I have tried without luck:

- URL-encoding the `key`  parameter
- Using `applicationKey` instead of `key`, but that seems to be part of the older API
- Generating new access_token in case the other one would've been invalidated for whatever reason
- Passing `access_token` as a query parameter same as for non-team sites, despite the documentation saying that it's not supported
- Revoking access to the app and then granting it again

From what I can see, I do nothing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this URL: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered/?team_url=stackoverflow.com%2fc%2ffoosite&site=stackoverflow&key=u9eRD30bklGv9t9gzDRSAQ((` you're passing a `team_url` parameter. That's not the right name, it should be `team` instead. You *are* passing the correct value.

Comment: Wow thank you. To think I had missed such an obvious detail. It works like a charm, thank you once again! :)

Comment: You're welcome. If it's any consolation, both the resident moderator and I had some troubles getting it to work as well. We both missed the fact that `stackoverflow.com/c/` needs to be part of the `team` parameter.

Comment: Maybe a more helpful error message would not be too much to ask for? Passing an invalid parameter should, in my opinion, yield another error message.

Comment: The problem is that without the `team` parameter, the API tries to parse it as a 'regular' API request. Many APIs ignore parameters unknown to them for forward/backward compatibility reasons.