# Stack OverflowTesting

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

How can I use Stack Overflow for Teams with Stack Exchange API combined?

I have tried creating a stack app and using client ID in Stack Exchange API.

I made a localhost application to implement Stack Overflow for Teams integration and hosted it through ngrok.

Later, I registered hosted app in stack apps and got the client ID and key. I then made an API request using the url

`https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=<ClientID>&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://fc7d77b5d7b3.ngrok.io/`

But then I don't get any response for the API. I assume here's where I have to get access token as response.

Is there anything I am doing wrong in this process?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams)? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: I am struck at getting access token. my authorisation API call with client ID and redirect URL is failing.

Comment: The documentation page I linked to says you need a different scope, it needs to have something like `access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/pickles` as well.

Comment: I tried that too... But since it's not working, I am trying this.

https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=<client-id>&scope=access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/<team_name>&redirect_uri=https://fc7d77b5d7b3.ngrok is the API I used.

It says "Channel not found"

Is it available for free slack team or only for basic and business versions?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have a free Stack team. You can try escaping the special characters like [this user](https://stackapps.com/q/8202/34061) did. Otherwise, I'm out of options.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll try that and let you know if it is working for me